# how can send blog.urls to my main page

Tags: python, django

I have a blog application and application has  a urls.py which includes generic view

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r'^', ListView.as_view(
                        queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-created")[:2],
                        template_name='index.html')),
)
```

I send 2 data.

In main project urls.py like that:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r"^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),
    url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r"^blog/", include('blog.urls')),

)
```

I can see retrieved datas from db 127.0.0.1/blog/ I want to also see in 127.0.0.1 I mean in the start page.
I add this:

```
  url(r"^$", include('blog.urls), direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),
```

But does not work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think `url(r"^$", include('blog.urls))` is enough .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should Work, seems you have missed the closing of single quotes on your urls.py.I am using this and it works fine.

```
  (r'^$',process.internal.views.HomePage.as_view(template_name='homepage.html')),
```

Comment: and what space after `template_name='homepage.html',` indicates ??? i m just kidding.......i think your answer should works...

Comment: oops! sorry...i just copied from VIM seems SO has added some spaces wile pasting...will remove it now..